# Difference Between Contrast Enhancement and Texture Enhancement in Images

Tags: image-processing

I have a very basic question. I understand that contrast enhancement is exaggerating the difference between the intensity of the adjacent structures and texture in an image is the repeating geometric patterns in an image. But what is exactly texture enhancement? Does enhancing contrast in an image automatically enhance texture also? Can someone explain this with an example. By looking at an image, how can one identify if the image needs contrast enhancement or texture enhancement? Or how does one identify, if an algorithm has done contrast enhancement or texture enhancement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually Contrast Enhancement is [Element / Pixel Wise Operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise) in [Digital Image Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_image_processing).

It means it adjusts the value of a pixel based only in its value.
In order to increase contrast we usually push bright values to be brighter and dark values to be darker ([S Shaped Contrast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(vision))).

When people try to enhance Texture they usually refer to the term Local Contrast.
Local contrast means we want to enhance contrast but using a [Neighborhood Operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighborhood_operation).
In the sense of contrast, we will push a pixel to be darker even if its value is bright but it is darker than its neighbors. Namely we have the locality sense of the operation.
For instance High Pass will increase local contrast.